# Unable to connect to host on different system from mongo shell in windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to connect to mongodb from my system to different system but i am getting following error-

MongoDB shell version v3.4.5
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.0.152:27017/
2017-06-23T18:06:50.643+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 192.168.0.108:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-06-23T18:06:50.644+0530 E QUERY    [thread1]

Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.0.152:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

I tried various solutions listed on stackoverflow but didn't find any solution yet.
Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

getaddrinfo() resolves domain names through the DNS protocol (which is not related the Netbios Naming System - reason why writing a Windows PC Name is usually a bad idea). Depending of the underlying implementation of the function it might or might not be able to resolve Netbios Names.

Usually using a Netbios computer name is a bad idea, you should rely on a proper DNS architecture.

If you have the exact same error with a mongodb:// URL using solely an IP address, it's weird... Please provide more details on the IP address try case.

Also ensure that the server is not firewalled. Try a netcat connection using netcat for windows:

```
nc IP 27017 -vv
```

should say 'Connected'

Netcat for Windows: https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/

Comment: Re-edited mine, try to inspect connectivity first with netcat and say what happens

Comment: i have tried nc it is giving me error "Host_Not_Found"

Comment: Wait, when you type "nc.exe [IPv4 ADDRESS] 27017 -vv" it says 'Host_Not_Found' ? This, I do not understand. It should say something like Timeout, Refused or Connected... Do you have a route to the host? Does ping work? Is IPV4 enabled on your client?

Comment: i tried again...it is showing up following error-
inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA
(UNKNOWN) [192.168.0.152] 27017 (?): connection refused
sent 0, rcvd 0: NOTSOCK

Comment: Ok, try with "-nvv" next time so there is no reverse host lookup (PTR query...). What it says here is that the connection is refused, either because the service is firewalled (Windows Firewall ftw), or because the server is not up and running on that IP or the IP is a router and does no forwarding. Ensure that your server is binding to 0.0.0.0 and not localhost, it is a common source of error. The "netstat -anb" command on the server will show you if the port is in listen mode on the proper interface (but will not say for the firewall).

Comment: it is now showing open...i guess it means system is open to connection...but still when i tried to connect through mongo shell it is showing same error

Comment: Wow. There is no reason for netcat to say closed and say open if you changed nothing on server side! (I don't think the reverse name resolution is at cause here)... Any IP conflict maybe? Try to sniff the traffic with Wireshark and see what you get from the TCP SYN packet sent to the server. Or maybe if you can update your OP to include a screenshot... Also your log shows another IP (192.168.0.108:27017)... Do you have some Replica Set config stuff loaded?

Comment: yes i am trying to replicate my database through mongo shell...that's why i need to establish connection between my system and target system...and what i found through many trials is my system is unable to connect to target machine while other cases are going fine (my system can be connected from other system,my system can connect to third system) means no problem in source system.

Comment: It seems there are connection issues with your replica set servers (they appear in the logs of your mongoshell as failed). This is just an impression, but it seems you have network issue (routing or server port exposition issue) which prevents the connection to work. I cannot be really more helpful on this, sorry :-/

Comment: I found the issue.....it was due to anti-virus installed on target system..which enables firewall and blocks connection. i turned it off now from antivirus application..and now it is working.

Thank You bro for all your support :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect to mongodb server hosted in another machine, you should be sure that your mongodb server allows connections from addresses other than `127.0.0.1`

In the `mongod.conf` there should be some network interfaces configuration:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

To allow any machine to connect to your server the bindIp should be set to: `0.0.0.0`